# How can the arguments get passed to the class if the class has no parameters?

Tags: python, class, oop, init

I could be lacking of very basic python basis. I'm handling a script made by others.

I have a script, let's say `My_Class`, in which the code is:

```
import thing1
import thing_2
...etc

class My_Class:

    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2 ...etc):
        self.argument_1 = arg1
        self.argument_2 = arg2
        ...etc
```

Is it correct that my_class has `__init__` whose arguments are not passed as arguments to my_class? (my_class does not have arguments at all)

How can the arguments `arg1, arg2 ...etc` be passed to `my_class` if the class has no parameters?

Shouldn't it be

```
import thing1
import thing_2
...etc

class My_Class(arg1, arg2 ...etc):

    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2 ...etc):
        self.argument_1 = arg1
        self.argument_2 = arg2
        ...etc
```

instead?

Note:

The class does not get instantiated, only its method are called, directly on the class, i.e:

```
My_Class(arg1, arg2 ...etc).method_1()
```

Comment: No, your first snippet is correct. The 'parameters' to a class are other classes you want to inherit from. Exercise: How do you instantiate `my_class`?

Comment: ``My_Class(arg1, arg2 ...etc).method_1()`` also instantiates the class. Then it calls a method on the instance and throws the instance a way afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: The "signature" of a class is defined by its `__init__` and/or `__new__` method.

---

The `class` statement is an implicit call to the [metaclass](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-metaclass)*. Any arguments of the `class` statement, including the bases, are consumed by the metaclass. The metaclass is responsible to use the class name, arguments and body to create the actual class object.

```py
#              v arguments passed to the metaclass
class My_Class(arg1, arg2, ...):
    ...
```

Notably, these are the arguments *passed to* the metaclass. In common cases, these are just the base classes; passing or even expecting other arguments is only needed for advanced cases.

When calling a class, as in `My_Class(arg1, arg2, ...)`, this passes the arguments to the class' `__init__` and/or `__new__`. As such, **`__init__`/`__new__` define which parameters "a class" takes**.

```py
class My_Class:
#                      v parameters taken by the class
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2 ...etc):
        self.argument_1 = arg1
        self.argument_2 = arg2
```

---

*This is a slight simplification of how metaclasses work. There are various levels of indirection that are not needed to understand the broad picture.

Answer (score 6):

I hope this information gives you a better understanding of why we can call our classes, where do those arguments go, where are the class's parameters and etc.

So, let's talk about `__call__` :

Think about implementing `__call__` inside your class. It enables the instance of the class to be callable in other words, "this" is the reason you can put `()` after your instance right ? And when you call your instances this way, `__call__` is the actual method that is getting called ! You could pass arguments when you are calling the instance if you define them in the `__call__` method as parameters.

```py
class A:
    def __call__(self, arg):
        print('It is calling', arg)

instance = A()
instance('foo')
```

**Now we know that classes themselves are instances --> of type `type`:**

```py
class A:
    pass

print(isinstance(A, type))  # True
```

So there has to be a `__call__` method in "their" class(better to say *metaclass*) and of course there is one in `type`. That's the reason we can put `()` after the class to call it and pass arguments to it.

When you put parentheses in front of you class, you are actually calling this `__call__` method of the class `type` with the given arguments here `arg1`, `arg2` ...

Wait, But where is `__init__` ? where is `__new__` ? How do *they* get called ?

In fact they get called **inside** the `__call__` method of the class `type` with exactly those arguments you passed. First `__new__` , [if it returns an instance of the class then `__init__` gets called like a normal instance method.](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__)

Now I'm going to demonstrate what I explained before: (The default metaclass of the all classes is `type` class, but I'm going to use mine to show you the details)

```py
class Mymeta(type):
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f"Metaclass's __call__ gets called with: {args} and {kwargs}")
        new_created_instance = cls.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        if isinstance(new_created_instance, cls):
            new_created_instance.__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        return new_created_instance


class A(metaclass=Mymeta):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        # return 10    # <-- If you uncomment this, __init__ won't get called.
        return super(A, cls).__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self, name, **kwargs):
        print(
            'This is printed only because'
            ' we called it inside `__call__` method of the meta class'
        )
        self.name = name


obj = A('soroush', age=5)
```

output :

```
Metaclass's __call__ gets called with: ('soroush',) and {'age': 5}
This is printed only because we called it inside `__call__` method of the meta class
```

Note two things, first, All the arguments that we passed in front of our class is passed directly to the `__call__` method of the metaclass. Second, as you can see `__call__` of the `Mymeta` is the caller for both `__new__` and `__init__`.

Comment: While I know what you are aiming at, I think this isn't helpful unless actually writing out what ``type.__call__`` does.

Comment: @quamrana In OP he mentioned "How can the arguments arg1, arg2 ...etc be passed to my_class if the class has no parameters" , I was trying to explain the rationale how these parameters are getting passed.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi You're right, I'm going to add more information

Comment: @quamrana calling an instance was just the introduction. The concept is the same. you can put parenthesis in front of your "any" object if you implement `__call__` in it's type !

Comment: Ok, I see where you are going with this.

Comment: Looks ok. I'm not an expert in python meta class, but I'm sure I've seen code like this which instantiates an object, then calls `__init__()` on the object and returns it.

Comment: It's probably worth adding that ``__init__`` is only called if ``__new__`` returns an instance of ``cls``.

Answer (score 2):

Your first snippet is correct:

```py
class My_Class:

    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2 ...etc):
        self.argument_1 = arg1
        self.argument_2 = arg2
        ...etc

#Instantiation
c = My_Class(arg1, arg2 ...etc)
#Call method on instance
c.method_1()
```

You definitely *are* instantiating the class: `My_Class(arg1, arg2 ...etc)` is interpreted by python as:

1. Instantiate an object.
2. Call `__init__()` on that object (with arg1, arg2 ...etc in your case)

In `python` the `__init__()` method is considered synonymous with the term 'constructor' used in other languages.

Also note that in my snippet above the variable `c` hangs onto the instance unlike your snippet.

Comment: ok, I maybe get it. 

First: I am instantiating the class but not saving that instance,

Second: I don't need to specify the arguments of the `__init__` method in the class arguments (where the class is defined) as well, right?

Comment: First, you *are* saving the instance implicitly, but only long enough to make the call to `method_1()`. Second the syntax of instantiating a class *looks* like you are giving the class some parameters, whereas python applies those parameters to the `__init__()` method.

Comment: Ok, I was just wondering how could the arguments be passed to the `__init__` method if the class was declared as "with zero arguments", but ok, I now understand how things works. Thanks!